# Stream video from PC to smartphone via bluetooth with 32feet

Tags: c#, bluetooth, obex, 32feet

Is is possible to steram a video from my PC to my Smartphone via bluetooth using the 32feet library and an android smartphone?

I want to do this without having a dedicated app installed on the smartphone.

I came across the OBEX protocol for files, and i know that you can stream music but i couldn't find any examples for video. Thanks!

Its safe to assuem that latency / bandwidth will not be a problem as its a very low res video.

Answer (score -1):

I dont actually think that you can via Bluetooth, becuse of the poor bandwith between those devices. I think Bluetooth 2.0 has like 80kbits/s or something.

Comment: Yeah i know, you'll be better with using Samba file sharing, you can download it for free on play market, or you can use ftp services from your router.